# How to shorten this eloquent command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have used this Eloquent command to get some data from the database table:

```
$categories = Category::where('category_type',2)->orWhere('category_type',3)->orWhere('category_type',4)->get();

return view('admin.categories.index', compact('categories'));
```

So I want `category_type` of **2**,**3** and **4** but I wanted to shorten this command, so I tried this instead:

`$categories = Category::where('category_type',[2,3,4,5])->get();`

But it does not work properly and only show data with `category_type` of **2**!

So the question is how can I shorten these `orWhere` commands? Is there any way for doing that?

Comment: You have to use `whereIn()` for an array of IDs (or values)... Just like you can't do `WHERE id = (2, 3, 4, 5)` in SQL, it's `WHERE id IN (2, 3, 4, 5)`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try whereIn()...

```
<?php

$categories = Category::whereIn('category_type',[2,3,4])->get();

return view('admin.categories.index', compact('categories'));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Comment: I would also recommend using `whereIntegerInRaw` if "category_type" is an INT. Much more efficient for whereIn on integers!

Comment: Oh right - never heard of it - thanks.

Comment: I discovered it after benchmarking some bigs `whereIn`. The requests were slower and slower with the `whereIn` parameter array increasing in size. I switched to `whereIntegerInRaw ` and saw HUGE improvements. But you need to query on integers.

Comment: But I'd imagine when only passing a few integers the difference is negligible is it?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. On a small number of integers, it's negligible. But still good to know when your whereIn starts to get bigger (mine where 300 to 2k IDs)

Answer (score 1):

This might be an overkill, but turn your glare into:https://github.com/rinvex/laravel-categories.

It's quite hard at the beginning, but gives lots of stuff instead.

Remember that in laravel you can go local/global scope inside your model https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes

```
public function scopePopular($query)
{
    return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
}
```

You can chain queries this way. The sample is from docs. Don't even think about 'repository pattern'. In my opinion it violates the above functionality and makes your code a bunch of mess. Just play around and make your queries inside model.

When you find yourself in hard situation, when you need to create something from few models involved (model aggregation), you might think about services/helpers/WHATEVER. The same role is given to view models in MVVM, as they prepare data for controller.

These are heavy logic classes, which make most of your work behind and they are called by controller/command-line/anything.

Comment: Hi! Do you have an example where this rinvex/laravel-categories is used? :)